# UPnP Control from terminal

Tags: linux, upnp

I would like to be able to control a UPnP Router from the terminal in linux.
I don't mind what language the software is in, but Ruby/Python/PHP would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you wish to accomplish. Perhaps this list of "upnp" related packages (Gentoo) will prove useful to you.

```
Net-UPnP
    http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-UPnP/
    Perl extension for UPnP
miniupnpc
    http://miniupnp.free.fr/
    Python bindings for UPnP client library
kio-upnp-ms
    https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/base/kio-upnp-ms
    A upnp KIO slave for KDE
gupnp-dlna
    http://gupnp.org/
    Library that provides DLNA-related functionality for MediaServers
upnpscan
    http://www.cqure.net/wp/upnpscan/
    Scans the network for UPNP capable devices
gupnp
    http://gupnp.org/
    An object-oriented framework for creating UPnP devs and control points
gupnp-av
    http://gupnp.org/
    A small utility library that aims to ease the handling UPnP A/V profiles
gupnp-igd
    http://gupnp.org
    This is a library to handle UPnP IGD port mapping for GUPnP.
gupnp-ui
    http://gupnp.org
    Collection of simple GTK+ widgets on top of GUPnP.
gupnp-vala
    http://gupnp.org/
    Vala bindings for the GUPnP framework
```

```
libupnp
    http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/
    An Portable Open Source UPnP Development Kit
miniupnpc
    http://miniupnp.free.fr/
    UPnP client library and a simple UPnP client
autoupnp
    https://bitbucket.org/mgorny/autoupnp/
    Automatic open port forwarder using UPnP
gupnp-tools
    http://gupnp.org/
    Free replacements of Intel UPnP tools that use GUPnP.
miniupnpd
    http://miniupnp.free.fr/
    MiniUPnP IGD Daemon
```

Comment: @nickw444 Did any of these prove useful?

Comment: No idea, I just searched for upnp in the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jalder/UPnP

This project hasn't been maintained in a while,but it is UPnP for php

From the description:

This library aims to be a convenient set of classes for controlling UPnP devices on a network. Some service specific classes for devices that leverage UPnP/SSDP may also be included such as the Roku (ecp, simplevideoplayer, and firefox), Chromecast (castv2), XBMC. Any device that can be discovered via SSDP will be considered for inclusion. Should mDNS be implemented in the future, package name may be changed to better reflect its role/purpose.